# Understanding char array initialization behavior

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program in which I am initializing a char array as follows

```
char array[28] = "\19TTTxxxxxxx Protocol\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
```

But the above statement gives a warning that "initializer string too long ". But when I change it to `\20`, it doesn't give the warning.

Can someone explain whats going on here?

Answer (score 2):

`"\20"` is a single character with octal value 020. `"\19"` is two characters, the first having octal value 01 and the second being `'9'`.

9 is not an octal digit.

Comment: For more detail, check out the spec, section **6.4.4.4 Character constants**.